# Insertar correlativo a un campo de ID en SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

actualmente estoy haciendo una exportación con este Script:

```
/* FromTable  1:Otrntransaction, 2:OtrnTrnTaxAmount, 3:Marckup  */ SELECT '1' AS FromTable, T1.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, T1.PostingDate AS Fecha, T2.AccountNo AS Folio, 
                         CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS SubFolio, T5.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T1.Reference AS Referencia, ID_TrnCode AS IdTipoTransaccion, 
                         T3.ShortName AS TipoTransaccion, T3.Name AS ShortName, T1.AmountPur AS Monto, T1.Comment AS Comentario
FROM            otrnTransaction AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         oaccAccount AS T2 ON T2.ID_Account = T1.ID_Account LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         prCode AS T3 ON T3.ID_Code = T1.ID_TrnCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         rmRoom AS T5 ON T5.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
WHERE T2.AccountNo = 34339
UNION ALL
SELECT        '2' AS FromTable, T1.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, T1.PostingDate AS Fecha, T2.AccountNo AS Folio, CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS SubFolio, 
                         T5.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T1.Reference AS Referencia, T0.ID_TaxCode AS IdTipoTransaccion, T3.ShortName AS TipoTransaccion, T3.Name AS ShortName, T0.Amount AS Monto, T1.Comment AS Comentario
FROM            otrnTrnTaxAmount AS T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         otrnTransaction AS T1 ON T0.ID_Trn = T1.ID_Trn LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         acTrnCodeGLDepPL AS T4 ON T4.ID_TrnCode = T0.ID_TaxCode AND T4.ID_DepartmentalPL = T1.ID_DepartmentalPL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         oaccAccount AS T2 ON T2.ID_Account = T1.ID_Account LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         prCode AS T3 ON T3.ID_Code = T0.ID_TaxCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         rmRoom AS T5 ON T5.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
WHERE T2.AccountNo = 34339
UNION ALL
SELECT        '3' AS FromTable, T1.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, T1.PostingDate AS Fecha, T2.AccountNo AS Folio, CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS SubFolio, 
                         T5.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T1.Reference AS Referencia, T1.ID_MarkupCode AS IdTipoTransaccion, T3.ShortName AS TipoTransaccion, T3.Name AS ShortName, T1.AmountMarkup AS Monto, 
                         T1.Comment AS Comentario
FROM            otrnTransaction AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         oaccAccount AS T2 ON T2.ID_Account = T1.ID_Account LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         prCode AS T3 ON T3.ID_Code = T1.ID_TrnCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         acTrnCodeGLDepPL AS T4 ON T4.ID_TrnCode = T1.ID_MarkupCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         rmRoom AS T5 ON T5.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
WHERE        (T1.ID_MarkupCode IS NOT NULL) AND T2.AccountNo = 34339
ORDER BY SubFolio
```

Dando como resultado los siguientes registros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les explico rápidamente el funcionamiento, la consulta devuelve las transacciones de una cuenta en el sistema con el que trabajo (sistema de hotelería). Según funcionamiento de dicho sistema las transacciones se guardan en una tabla (OtrnTransaction) y los impuestos de las transacciones se guardan en otra tabla (OtrnTrnTaxAmount). Por lo que para reconstruir toda la cuenta hago 2 UNIONS para extrarla de manera completa. Hasta aquí todo bien

El inconveniente es que las transacciones originales son almacenadas mediante un ID y los impuestos que se alojan en otra tabla se almacenan mediante el mismo ID, según la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pretendo exportar esta información me da un error por que en la base de datos donde quiero depositar la información no permite duplicados en el campo IdDiarioTrans, por lo que necesito agregar un correlativo 1, 2, 3 por cada transacción para que no se repita el ID.

No sé si me dí a entender bien, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Y el problema no estaria en la tabla de destino? no alcanza con cambiar la definicion de ese campo y agregar otro ID autonumerico?

Comment: Hay un par de formas de reconvertir el mismo `id` en 3 distintos, ahora, después no vas a necesitar desde la tabla destino acceder al `id` original? Sino el comentario de @gbianchi es la respuesta.

Comment: Sí, sería lo más fácil pero el desarrollador de la otra tabla de destino (Que no somos nosotros) no quiere cambiar las definiciones de la tabla, porque "Le lleva mucho tiempo"

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es una respuesta, igual siempre me gustaría saber como hacerlo por si me sirve en un futuro pero lo que hice al final fue crear una tabla CUSTOM con un auto-increment, insertar allí los datos de la vista y luego de allí exportarlos a la otra base de datos, exportando en el campo del ID, en lugar del ID de la transacción, el autoincrement que configuré.